# Building an arglist for Unix program

Tags: c, unix, command-line-arguments

In order to execute a program multiple times based on the user input, I need to vary the arglist array sent to the execution function.  For the most part, I have it working, except for setting the final flag to signify which split function to use from information gain, first index and gini coefficient

This program has three different split functions to create a decision tree based on a training and testing dataset.  I set up the arglist to mimic the traditional CLI input so these are valid inputs:

`./decision voting 5`

`./decision -train voting-train-1 -test voting-test-1 -out voting.out -[i, s, g]`

What the first command does is executes all three split functions on all voting-*-* files from 1 to 5, whereas the second does it with a singular dataset.

I have a temp arg array which is built depending on the iteration, and when it comes time to add the final flag, this is what I've done:

```
//flag pointers
char *igFlag= "-i";
char *faFlag= "-s";
char *giFlag= "-g";

//copy temp array to specific arglist
igInput= cli;
faInput= cli;
giInput= cli;

//set information gain flag and null
igInput[7]= igFlag;
igInput[8]= '\0';

//set first attribute flag and null
faInput[7]= faFlag;
faInput[8]= '\0';

//set gini coefficient and null
giInput[7]= giFlag;
giInput[8]= '\0';
```

The issue here is when `faInput[7]= faFlag` executes, it changes `igInput[7]` to match and then when `giInput[7]= giFlag` is executed, all three arrays have matching [7] pointers.

I came across a similar issue when using the same temp pointer for a integer array, but that issue was fixed via using differently named variables.  This issue is happening even though I have distinct variables that have nothing to do with each other.

**SOLVED**

In response to AusCBloke's request to know how I solved this problem, here goes.

First, I decided that I didn't need multiple input strings, just the one where the last slot was to be modified.  So I cut away two of the xxInput strings and used only one.

I ended up needing more flags at the end, and rather than end up with duplicate code, I created a `char flag[5]` containing the flags to be used.  These were then called from inside a for loop, where the flag used was the current index value.

All in all, this approach ended up removing about 30 lines of un-needed code.

Comment: Have you considered using getopt and getopt_long? These are the standard ways of handling command line options.

Comment: ^^ Should be an answer. Because it *is* the answer.

Comment: You missed the point of the question- I'm not asking about parsing a command line input, but rather building them.  getopt parses the CLI and I don't see how it fits here

Comment: Yeah I just realised that. You can keep the code similar to what you have if you `exec` (or whatever you're calling) after changing the flag, you don't necessarily need to copy the whole of `cli` in order to reuse it. Editted my post.

Comment: How'd you end up going with solving your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making something trivial into a nightmare. My understanding is that you want to run the command 3 times, with `-i`, `-s`, or `-g` depending on the iteration. So do this:

```
char opt[] = "-i", *cmd[] = {
    "decision", "-train", "voting-train-1", "-test", "voting-test-1",
    "-out", "voting.out", opt, 0
};
/* use first command line */
opt[1] = 's';
/* use second command line */
ops[1] = 'g';
/* use third command line */
```

Comment: I picked yours as the answer since you came closest to my eventual solution.  See my edit for clarification

Answer (score 3):

> The issue here is when `faInput[7]= faFlag` executes, it changes
>   `igInput[7]` to match and then when `giInput[7]= giFlag` is executed,
>   all three arrays have matching [7] pointers.

```
//copy temp array to specific arglist
igInput= cli;
faInput= cli;
giInput= cli;
```

You're not copying `cli`, your setting each of those `char *` to point to `cli`. Therefore `igInput[7] == faInput[7] == giInput[7] == cli[7]`

Allocate memory for `ig/fa/gaInput` and `memcpy` `cli` into them, if you don't use meagar's suggestion of `getopt`.

**EDIT:** Oh wait you're trying to pass these arguments to something else, not read them in? And is `cli` like some sort of `argv`? If that actually is the case and `cli` is a `char **` 
then you could just keep it similar to the way you have it, ie:

```
cli[8] = NULL;

cli[7] = igFlag;
execv(cli[0], cli);

cli[7] = faFlag;
execv(cli[0], cli);

cli[7] = giFlag;
execv(cli[0], cli);
```

Comment: Or, since this is Unix, instead of malloc()ating and memcpy()ing, just strdup().

Comment: Oh yeah good old `strdup`, if he wants to copy the whole `cli` he could do that. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't copy the `cli` array to the various Input variables. It sets all three input pointers to point to the `cli` array. Since `igInput`, `faInput` and `giInput` all point to the same place, changing `faInput[7]` appears to modify `giInput[7]` as well, because they are both pointing to the same underlying data. You need to use [`memcpy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcpy#Function_overview) to copy array data around. But you should really use [`getopt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt) to process your args, as @meagar suggests.

```
//copy temp array to specific arglist
igInput= cli;
faInput= cli;
giInput= cli;
```